# Please run mysql_upgrade в MySQL логах

Tags: mysql

Начал получать такое сообщение в логах мускуля. Может кто-то подсказать что это и если запустить mysql_upgrade не приведет ли это к крашу БД?

> 2019-03-26T16:31:27.107565Z 7 [Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_table_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade
>
> 2019-03-26T16:31:27.107573Z 7 [Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_index_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade
>
> 2019-03-26T16:31:27.107862Z 7 [Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_table_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade

Comment: *если запустить mysql_upgrade не приведет ли это к крашу БД?* Вообще-то запуск mysql_upgrade всегда начинают с полного бэкапа. Так что нет, ничего не случится. Ежели что, восстановишь.

Comment: @Akina бэкап то не грех сделать, согласен, просто все равно будет не приятно если БД прода упадет, еще ой как неприятно!

Comment: Да не даст тебе никто гарантий! На ЛЮБОМ процессе всё может ёкнуться, вообще на любом. Ну ежели не задастся - снесёшь MySQL, поставишь заново, вернёшь бэкап. Делов-то...